# Getting your nested div to behave like table cell

Tags: css, css-tables

I know about display: table/table-row/table-cell styles.
What if I want to apply table-cell style to deeper element in DOM structure and get the same effect.
Please, look at r2c1 cell. As you see it has other width then other cells in this column.
http://jsfiddle.net/forus/G6daP/3/
Is it possible to get autoresizing for this cell as well?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JoseFaeti/G6daP/13/) approach.

I don't know if you need the table display properties for that particular element, since you talked only about anto resizing.

If that's what you are looking for, I think this could be a solution.